# How to call window.location.pathname inline in ternary operator Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to write an conditional statement inline in **Angularjs**. Basically, I want to make it so when a tab is clicked on a page, the page is update to `aria-current="page"`. The way I was going to do this is to check if the tabs anchor `href` is equal to the current windows *pathname*. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out the correct syntax or ternary structure to make this work inline. The below code is not working for me.

`aria-current="{{ window.location.pathname == 'item.location' && 'page' || 'notpage'}}"`

In this case `item.location` is the value of the anchors href.

Comment: what is page and notpage??

Comment: page is the value for aria-current when you want screen readers to understand that the current anchor link is the page in view. Notpage could be 'null', basically just something filler other than 'page'

Comment: I should have specified that this is for Angular 1. I figured people would understand that by referencing Angularjs

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
aria-current= (window.location.pathname == item.location)?'page':'notpage';
```

For angular 
do something like this in controller

```
 $rootScope.location = $location;
```

then add following

```
aria-current="{{location.path() ==item.location?'page':'notpage'}}"
```

Comment: This does not work. the source code is just showing that code string inline. Is that syntax for angular1?

Comment: Updated for angular